# Accessing remote database server from android app

Tags: java, android, sql-server, database, server

I'm a beginner in Android dev, and I'm working on my android app project, which should has two levels of accesability. Base should have a list of products of a restaurant, and users(barmans) should be able to choose products from it in order to count orders prices.

From other side, owner of a restaurant, should be able to set, prices, add new products and so on.

What basic DB server solutions can be in this case? There wouldn't be a lot of products so productivity is not extremely valuable

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking here. Are you trying to ask which database system to use? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create all the logic on the server-side using any programming language you choose. And from the Android App just consume REST services.
You can do your own in heroku.com or any other free hosting site you find online (if it's not for commercial use).
Once you have all the back-end setup, you can continue the Android development.